# Function cannot access global variable outside of it

Tags: python

So I have a program that at its core is this

```
def first():
    global myvar
    myvar = "thing"
        def second():
            print myvar
```

but when it runs nothing happens, I honestly dont know what else to do

Comment: So you define a function and then what?  I don't know python but don't you need to call the function at some point?

Answer (score 1):

```
def first():
    global myvar
    myvar = "thing"
    def second():
        print myvar
    second()  #==>call the function or
    return second()  #return the second function

first()
```